# skype manager + Java

Tags: java, web-services, skype

I am trying to create (code using Java or php) an auto credit system "XYZ" using skype manager.  For example employee provides me with his skype username, I pass (call mathod) and system "XYZ" automatically invites him to accept my skype manager. After that system "XYZ" credits his skype acount for appropriate amount. Have anyone ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: I have not tried anything yet. I am just in a planing position. And first problem would be how to invite user to skype manager having user name using Java?

Answer (score 0):

Skype offers a [SDK](http://developer.skype.com/). So maybe you should start with the [documentation](http://developer.skype.com/public-api-reference).